# Website Image preload for faster loading

Tags: jquery, html, css

I`m trying to build a cool gallery for my photography website:

I thought i`m already done. On my computer i looks pretty cool, so i uploaded it to my Webspace on Webgo.

The problem is the loading time of the images, when loading the website the first time.

I build the masonry look with pure css. And the images are hard coded. Later i will fix this and load them via php.

Is there any possibility to get a faster image load? I already rendered the images down to max-width: 800px via photoshop.

Answer (score 1):

1. make thumbnails - make the images smaller, these are high resolution images and smaller ones will load much faster.
2. set up some sub-domains for images, this will let most modern browsers make multiple image requests simultaneously
   so right now you website is portfolio.marcelmerz.de
   so set up some sub domains for pictures e.g.
   img1.marcelmerz.de, img2.marcelmerz.de, img3.marcelmerz.de, and img4.marcelmerz.de

point all 4 sub domains to where your images are, then alternate the image urls to use the different sub-domains.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to optimize your images for the web.  You are loading a 1200px image for a 200-300px width thumbnail. This is why they are taking so long to load.  To optimize you can get the images to their natural size using an editing tool like photoshop and saving them out at a jpeg quality that suits your needs.  The lower the file size, the faster the images will load.  Not sure what tool you used to build out the page, but you could also implement a technique/plugin know as "Lazy Load".  This will allow to load the images as they come into view, loosening up some bandwidth for the images that load initially.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I already thought i optimized my images. The problem is, in mobile View i need a min resolution of a width of 768px, because the images are displayed in full witdth. But i will try Lazy Load. Thanks

Comment: For a website I implemented I have thumbnails that are 16px by 16px and I use this for the init load.  I then lazy load the proper size in.  This gives a nice effect of a blurred image then becoming very clear.